# How to show 10 slides per column with Swiper?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

I need to show 10 slides per column. I'm using Swiper. I need to have a view like in the image below. But `slidesPerColumn: 10` group slides and show it like `slidesPerColumn: 6`. How to provide a view like in the image below?

[image]

Code snippet (Swiper 4.4.6):
https://codepen.io/ZaAz28/pen/qBmQeeE

Code snippet (Swiper latest):
https://codepen.io/ZaAz28/pen/oNWJvLL

Comment: I think it is best if you either ditch Swiper, or don't have 10 slides per view, or make your won workaround via CSS. This is a known issue that as soon as you want more than 2 slides per column, Swiper strikes. [Here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3754) is a work around if you scroll a bit but I think ditching either Swiper or 10 slides per column might be the best thing to do.

Comment: Thank You a lot! No way to don't have 10 slides per view. And don't want to change Swiper because it's one of the best sliders. CSS works perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.swiper-wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto; // here is the amount of slidesPerColumn you want
      grid-auto-flow: column;

      & > .swiper-slide {
        height: fit-content;
      }
    }
```

Comment: instead of grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto.... you can use grid-template-rows: repeat(10, auto)

Answer (score 2):

When I used the above solution, I had errors with the bullets. So I found a more native solution.

You can just use 'grid':

```
const personSwiper = new Swiper(".person-slider", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  grid: {
    rows: 5, // your amount of slides
    fill: "row",
  },
});
```